# Word by word animation

Tags: ms-word, powerpoint, epub

I want do to word by word animation on a document. My document may be .doc .html .ppt. I think a macro in .doc may do a better job.

When the document is displayed I want to animate word by word by highlighting a word.

When I am speaking word should highlight and move to next word. This way I can sync my voice with the words.

I tried animation in PowerPoint but it displays word by word and it does not allow whole text to appear and then move around words.

Answer (score 0):

Linking an animation such as highlighting of text to a sound file is allowed in epub 3.0; details can be found in the IDPF's spec, in the [Media Overlay](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-mediaoverlays.html) section. The first thing that you will need to do is mark up the text at your required level of granularity--by word, it sounds like. So the xhtml should look like:

```
<p><span id="word1>This</span> <span id="word2">is</span> <span id="word3">a</span> <span id="word4">sample</span>.</p>
```

You'll also need the audio file in the epub, of course, and then a .smil file to link the two together. The .smil file looks like:

```
<par id="first">
  <text src="book.xhtml#word1"/>
  <audio src="audio/audio.mp3" clipBegin="0s" clipEnd="0.65s"/>
</par>
<par id="second">
  <text src="book.xhtml#word2"/>
  <audio src="audio/audio.mp3" clipBegin="0.66s" clipEnd="1.4s"/>
</par>
...
```

You'll have to include the `media-overlay` attribute for the xhtml file in the manifest in the content.opf as well:

```
<manifest>
<item id="book" href="book.xhtml" media-type="application/zhtml+xml" media-overlay="smil-file"/>
<item id="smil-file" href="book_audio.smil" media-type="application/smil+xml"/>
```